# How can I find or generate a sample LLVM project?

Tags: llvm, project, sample

In LLVM [documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#llvm-projects) regarding how to start a project, it mentions:

> (....)
>
> There are two ways that you can set all of these variables:
>
> (.....)
>
> You can use the pre-made LLVM sample project. This sample project
> includes Makefiles, a configure script that can be used to configure
> the location of LLVM, and the ability to support multiple object
> directories from a single source directory.

The problem is, I am not sure where this is located or how to generate this sample project within my LLVM installation - I have cloned LLVM project and compiled it.

In another place in documentation it was mentioned to be placed in `llvm/projects/samples`, however I was unable locating this, since the fonder does not contain any project (However, it contains a `CMakeLists.txt` and a `LLVMBuild.txt`, making me think I might be able to generate this).

Do I miss something very obvious here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed since release/3.5.x branch, however you can still find in release/2.4.x branch or lower.

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/release/3.4.x/llvm/projects